# While loop not including lower limit

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# by myself by book and would appreciate some help.
I want to create a simple console program to allow the user to enter two numbers to be the lower and upper limit. The program will then find all numbers that are divisible by a number (lets say 3). The code I have written so far works but there is one small problem it doesn't include the lower limit when finding divisible numbers. Probably it is the `num1++;` in the while loop that is causing the problem. Please take a look:

```
int num1, num2, result;

Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number to be the lower limit: ");
num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number to be the upper limit: \n");
num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

while (num1 <= num2)
{
    num1++;
    result = num1 % 3;

    if (result == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is divisible by 3.\n", num1);
    }

}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `num1` is increased right after entering the loop body. Place the `num1++;` line after the `if` block - to the very end of the loop body. To avoid such mistakes the `for(...)` loop is much more useful when iterating over consequent numbers.

Here is an example of rewriting your code with a `for` loop:

```
int num1, num2, result;

Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number to be the lower limit: ");
num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number to be the upper limit: \n");
num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (int current = num1; current <= num2; current++)
{
    result = current % 3;

    if (result == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is divisible by 3.\n", current);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about using the for loop at first but I don't know how to make it accept numbers from the user :-(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    int num1, num2, result;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number to be the lower limit: ");
    num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number to be the upper limit: \n");
    num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    while (num1 <= num2)
    {
        result = num1++ % 3;

        if (result == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is divisible by 3.\n", num1 - 1);
        }

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

the num1 will increase first time after divisible operation

Comment: Did you try it yourself? All the numbers this program prints are not divisible on 3.

Comment: I have replaced
num1++;
result = num1 % 3;
to
result = num1++ % 3;

Logic operation has not changed. This program works fine.